# Ambigous call for operator[] inside a nested class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, nested-class, ambiguity

I'm trying to make a data structure that has vector features to learn some C++. I'm currently stuck trying to compile code similar to this:

```
template<typename T>
class TestClass {
public:
    T* data;
    TestClass(const T& t) { 
        data = new T{ t };
    }
    ~TestClass(void) {}
    TestClass(const TestClass&) {}

    T& operator[](int k) { return *data; }
    const T& operator[](int k) const { return *data; }
    class NestedClass {
    public:
        NestedClass(void) {}
        ~NestedClass(void) {}
        T& operator*(void) { return operator[](0); }
    };

    NestedClass newNestedClass(void) {
        return new NestedClass();
    }
};
```

I'm getting an ambiguous call to overloaded function on my `operator*` function inside my nested class. Though I think I get the problem (how will the compiler know if its rhs/lhs) I'm not entirely sure how to fix it. I want to use the `operator[]` function for this.

I'm expecting these two print lines to print the exact same thing:

```
TestClass<int> t(1);
auto n = t.newNestedClass();
cout << t[0] << endl;
cout << *n << endl;
return 0;
```

Any advice?

Comment: The problem is that `operator[]` is not a member of `NestedClass`. You have to provide an object argument yourself. E.g. save a pointer to `TestClass`.

Comment: A nested class is just an ordinary class in a separate namespace, where the outer class provides the namespace. Other than that, it has no special connection to the outer class, like it is (I think) in Java.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with that concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator[]` that you defined for your `TestClass` is in no way "inherited" or somehow "embedded" in your nested class.

You can think of C++ nested classes as just ordinary classes, that live in a "nested namespace": `TestClass::NestedClass` in your sample code.

If you want an `operator[]` for your nested class, you have to define one from scratch (as you did for your `TestClass`).

---

**EDIT 1: Returning Classes (C++ Is *Not* Java)**

Note also that C++ is *not* like e.g. Java (with a pattern of allocating instances of classes with `new`, and relying on a garbage collector to automatically collect "garbage").
So, code like this:

> ```
>    NestedClass newNestedClass(void) {
>         return new NestedClass();
>     }
> ```

should not even compile.

If you returned a `NestedClass` instance dynamically allocated with `new`, you should return a **pointer** to it, e.g.:

```
   // Note the "*" for the returned pointer
   NestedClass* newNestedClass() {
        return new NestedClass();
   }
```

But, this is more of a Java pattern.

In C++, you may just want to return an instance of NestedClass *without* a `new` dynamic allocation; this should work just fine:

```
   NestedClass newNestedClass() {
        return NestedClass();
   }
```

---

**EDIT 2: Proper Resource Management**

Note also that you may want to make the `T* data;` member **`private`** for better encapsulation and information hiding. You are providing proper *public* accessors (like `operator[]` overloads) to access your class's data: expose the accessor member functions, *not* the data members.

Moreover, you *dynamically* allocated `data` on the heap using `new`. You must **release** the dynamically heap-allocated memory, to avoid memory (and resource) *leaks*.
A good place to do that is your class **destructor**, e.g.:

```
class TestClass {
private:
    T* data;

public:
    ...

    ~TestClass() {
        // Release resoruces dynamically allocated
        delete data;
    }
}
```

Note also that this code:

> ```
> data = new T{t};
> ```

just dynamically allocates a single instance of `T`, initializing it to the value `t`.

The corresponding cleanup code is:

```
delete data;
```

However, if you want to dynamically allocate an array of `T`s, the syntax is:

```
data = new T[elementCount];
// ... initialize data to some value...
```

and the corresponding cleanup syntax is:

```
delete[] data; // Note the []!!
```

Note also that, if you want to manually manage resources in your class, you should consider also defining **copy constructor** and **copy assignment** `operator=()` (see the so called [***Rule of Three***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)); and if you want to implement *move semantics*, you should also consider implementing **move constructor** and **move assignment** (in this case there's a corresponding *"Rule of 5"*).

But if you rely on already available **RAII resource managers**, like `std::vector`, you don't have to spend time, energy, and bug hunting, managing resources *manually*: it's all **automatically** managed by **`std::vector`**, or whatever container class you choose (in this case, you have a simple *"Rule of Zero"* :) i.e. the default compiler-generated copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, move assignment operator and destructor will do the tight thing.

But, of course, if this is a learning excercise, you may want to implement those special member functions by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on your edit section. I found this compile error after I've fixed my initial problem :)